# android Google maps : getLastLocation vs requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, google-play-services

I just need to understand this clearly, `getLastLocation()` method will give me the last known location and `requestLocationUpdates` will give me the current location every period of time.

now, i am developing a simple app to track mobile phones, which will be in cars.

my Question are :

1- how exactly `getLastLocation()` works, will this `last known location` be updated when the location change

2- which is better, using `getLastLocation()` to have the initial location then update the current location by using the method `onLocationChanged` or using `requestLocationUpdates` to have an up to date location every n sec ?

Comment: You pretty much answer it yourself: `getLastLocation() method will give me the last known location and requestLocationUpdates will give me the current location every period of time.`

Comment: will this last known location be updated when the location change ?

Comment: It returns a Location object that won't be updated further. Usually something that is updated periodically is done via a listener-method, e.g.: `LocationListener`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getLastLocation` gives you the last location which was there in `LocationClient`, it can be null sometimes, say if you don't have any other application installed which uses location services, that's a rare case as most phones have Google maps or some other location dependent apps installed.

getLastLocation is only helpful, when you want location for once and your done with it, but for location updates you should use `requestLocationUpdates`, and using a service, your application will always get notified, when the location changes.

I hope you are using the FusedLocation Provider from play services, so you can specify how fast location updates you need, to check cases of battery drain and performance.

Also to note here when you use `requestLocationUpdates` then only you will get any location change updates.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i just have 2 more points. 1) `Also to note here when you use requestLocationUpdates then only you will get any location change updates.` so if i am updating it every 1 sec but the mobie didnt move, it wont update, am i correct

2) `onLocationChanged` will it work any way whether i used `requestLocationUpdates ` or `getLastLocation` ? and will it update the `getLastLocation` ?

Comment: no! it won't! coz there was no location change, onLocationChange() will be called when there is any location changes vis, when you requested for them.

Similarly last location will also get updated, when there is a location change.

Answer (score 2):

so according to android docs getLastLocation() :-

> Returns the best most recent location currently available. If a
>   location is not available, which should happen very rarely, null will
>   be returned. The best accuracy available while respecting the location
>   permissions will be returned. This method provides a simplified way to
>   get location. It is particularly well suited for applications that do
>   not require an accurate location and that do not want to maintain
>   extra logic for location updates.

This is the problem with getLastLocation(),that it is not accurate and it may return null if it does not have any last known location in cache.I have faced this issue many times in my application.So for getting the accurate location you should use **requestLocationUpdates()** but define the interval according to your need at which time interval you want the updates as a very short time span may cause more power usage.